# Make div look like ListBox

Tags: c#, css, html, styles

I have a div which contains table.
I need somehow to change it style and make it look like ordinary ListBox.
Is it possible to do or all I can is to make several border changes? (If it so, how can I view ListBox standart style?)

```
<div id="Div1" runat="server">
   <table>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
      ...
   </table>
</div>
```

By simply words: ListBox have his specific border. I want to make div border looks like ListBox border.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: ...Post what? Div tags?

Comment: Yes your code to make properly or set fiddle

Comment: Em... okay but... for what purpose? It is simple div tag and table in it =_=

Comment: yes possible, but I Want to know how it look like, A picture will do

Answer (score 0):

**CSS code to have custom borders**

```
td
{
border-top:1px solid black;
border-botton:1px solid black;
}
```

The above code add a border only in the top and bottom, if this is what you expected